# An Inequality about norms

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am reading quotient-norms and came across the below inequality. However, I could not get any intuition or proof behind it. Is there any intuition behind this inequality?

$\inf_{t\in \mathbb{R}} \|\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{1}\|_{\infty}  = \frac{1}{2} \sup_{i,j} |x_i-x_j| $.

Here is what I was able to do.

Let $t^*$ be the minimizer on the left-hand-side. Then for any pair $i,j$,
$$0.5|x_i-x_j|\le 0.5( |x_i+t^*|+|x_j+t^*|) \le \|\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{1}\|_{\infty}.$$

The other side of the inequality remains to be shown. I'd appreciate any hints or suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @GA-Student.  I think this contribution makes the question quite good. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m=\inf x_i$ and $M=\sup x_i.$ For any fixed $t$ we have $$\inf (x_i+t)= m+t,\qquad \sup (x_i + t)= M+t.$$ Therefore $$\|x+t{\bf 1}\|_\infty=\max (|m+t|,|M+t|). $$ The infimum of the right hand side is  attained for $t=-(m+M)/2$ and is equal $(M-m)/2.$
Hence
$$ \inf_t\|x+t{\bf 1}\|_\infty= {1\over 2}(M-m)$$
Moreover $$M-m = \sup_{i,j} |x_i-x_j|$$