# Analytically expressing an infimum over $l_1$ norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Building on my previous question, [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4403364){https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4403364}, where I wanted to prove the expression
$$ \inf_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \|\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{1}\|_{\infty} = \frac{1}{2}\sup_{i,j}|x_i-x_j|,$$
we can change the norm on the LHS to the euclidean norm and can derive an expression for
$$\inf_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \|\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{1}\|_2 $$ by differentiating with respect to $t$ and setting the derivative equal to 0. Is it possible to compute an analytical expression for
$$\inf_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \|\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{1}\|_1,$$ that is, when the norm is the $l_1$-norm.

Comment: There is a problem, when you allow infinite dimensional spaces as the constant sequence $\bf1$ does not belong to $\ell^p$ for $p<\infty.$

Comment: For my purpose, a finite-dimensional $\mathbf{x}$ works, say $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Thank you for pointing out; I missed specifying that.

Comment: There is no analytical expression, but $t$ solves the problem **iff** it is a median of the $x_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are convex problems can be solved readily using the subgradient. Since this is convex, the first order conditions are necessary and sufficient.

For the first, Let $\psi(t) = \max_k f_k(t) $ where $f_k(t) = |t-x_k|$ and we wish to find
$\min_t \psi(t)$. The subgradient is given by
$\partial \psi(t) = \operatorname{co} \cup_{k \in I(t)} \partial f_k(t)$, where
$I(t) = \{ k \mid f_k(t) = \psi(t) \}$. Note that we have
$\partial f_k(t) = \begin{cases} \{+1\}, & t> x_k \\ [-1,1],& t=x_k, \\
\{-1\}, & t <x_k\end{cases}$. At a $\min$ we have $0 \in \partial \psi(t)$.
Hence one of the following must be true, either there are indices $k,k' \in I(t)$ such that $\partial f_k(t) = \{+1\}, \partial f_{k'}(t) = \{-1\}$, or
there is some index $k \in I(t)$ such that $\partial f_k(t) = [-1,1]$. In the latter case, we must have $t=x_k$ for all $k$. In the first case we have
$\psi(t) = t-x_k = x_{k'}-t$ from which we get $t = {1 \over 2} (x_k+x_{k'})$
and so in both cases we have $\psi(t) = {1 \over 2}\max _{i,j} |x_i-x_j|$.

For the second, let $\psi(t) = \sum_k f_k(t) $, this time we have
$\partial \psi(t) = \sum_k \partial f_k(t)$. Let $n_t,e_t.p_t$ be the numbers of
indices for which $t<x_k, t=x_k, t>x_k$ respectively. A little work shows that
$\partial \psi(t) = \{p_t-n_t\}+[-e_t,e_t]$, and that $0 \in \partial \psi(t)$ **iff** $|p_t-n_t| \le e_t$ **iff** the indices can be partitioned
into index two sets $I_1,I_2$ of equal size where $I_1 = \{ k \mid t \le x_k \}$ and $I_2 = \{ k \mid t \ge x_k \}$ **iff** $t$ is a median of the $x_k$.

Comment: Why the down vote?